# ModuleNotFoundError for matplotlib and pandas in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, pylance

When I import matplotlib.pylot as plt and pandas as pd in my code and run it, I get the error in the terminal saying "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'" and "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'" (pandas error will occur when I have the import pandas module on the first line of my code). When I hover over the two modules, the message "Import 'matplotlib.pyplot' could not be resolved from source" and "Import 'pandas' could not be resolved from source" will appear. How can I fix these problems so that my code will properly run and not receive those error messages?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

temp_data = pd.read_csv("temperature_data.csv", header=0) 

plt.plot(temp_data['Year'], temp_data['Anomaly'], color='gray')
plt.ylabel('Temperature Anomalies in Celsius')
plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.title('Change in Temperatures')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Just install matplotlib and pandas?If you think you have it installed, maybe code uses another enviornment than u usually use.

Comment: I found that I didn't allow scripts to run in my Visual Studio Code, so I enabled it in my terminal and it allowed the matplotlib and pandas module to download. When my scripts was disabled, the program wouldn't allow me to install the matplotlib and pandas module, until I enabled it to allow scripts. Now my code runs smoothly without producing any errors.